# Populate Makefile Variable with For Loop

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the files `args.cpp/h`, `output.cpp/h`, and `computation.cpp/h`. I want to use both their object files and their header files as dependencies.

I'm trying to minimize code duplication by creating a makefile variable with just their base names then populating two other makefile variables with their object file names and header file names, respectively.

Here is what I'm trying so far, with no results:

```
BASES = args output computation
OBJS =
CODE =
for base in $(BASES); do \
    OBJS += $$base.o ; \
    CODE += $$base.h ; \
done;
```

Am I even approaching this the right way? If so, how do I fix the for loop? If not, what makefile approach should I use to eliminate the code duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a mix of shell and make and that can't work that way. You can do something along those lines if you really wanted but there's no reason to do it that way.

```
BASES = args output computation
OBJS = $(addsuffix .o,$(BASES))
CODE = $(addsuffix .h,$(BASES))
```

or

```
CODE = args.h output.h computation.h
OBJS = $(CODE:.h=.o)
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the first solution because it breaks the files down to their most fundamental similarity and requires the least typing.

Comment: The least typing when? It is significantly more bytes of make code than the latter is but also introduces an extra (and extraneous) variable for no reason but <shrug>. They both work so it doesn't matter.

Comment: The least typing as in `args` vs `args.h`. This pattern will be copied to new makefiles across our entire system. Some will require `args`, some will require `computation`, some will require both. For a person entering a new `BASES` line into their makefile, that solution will be easier to understand.

Comment: I also have to `addprefix` to create a `PATHS` variable with an external path for each base that both the `CODE` and the `OBJS` will derive from, which is another reason the `BASES` solution works better for me.

Comment: Ah, as a template for a system where BASES will change but the transformations necessary will not that's a more reasonable decision. As to the `addprefix` bit you can always assign a variable to itself with a transformation (as long as that assignment is immediate (uses `:=`)).